# Design a MongoDB schema over springBoot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to design a service, with following structure using MongoDB over SpringBoot.
Can anyone suggest how I should model my collection. The area where I am stuck is, if let's say, my sim is "Vodafone", then VodafoneItem must be present in my Json, but if sim is "Airtel", then only AirtelItem should be present.

```
{
    name: "ABC",
    notifications:[
    {
       sim: "vodafone",
       vodafoneItem:{
         property: "AAA",
         rate: "xyz"
       }
    },
    {
       sim: "airtel",
       airtelItem:{
         property: "AAA",
         features: "xyzAA"
       }
    }
   ]
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want polymorphic documents. Spring Data Mongo handles this well. I recommend using `@TypeAlias("airtel")`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?